# PHP script not creating and writing a JSON file

Tags: c#, php, json

I have a PHP script which get it's post data from my C# code. My C# code sends POST data to my PHP script including a base64 string and a filename. With these two pieces of data it should create a JSON file in the folder JSON with the filename and then it should write the decoded base64 string to the file it just created. After this it should save the JSON data to a database. But there's one problem, It doesn't create the JSON file and it saves blank data to my database. Here is what I have so far:

PHP:

```
<?php
$link = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);
if($link ->connect_errno) 
{
    echo 'Database connection wrong<br/>';
}
else 
{
    if(isset($_POST['filename']) && isset($_POST['b64string']))
    {
        $jsonstring = base64_decode($_POST['b64string']);
        $filename = $_POST['filename'] . '.json';

        $create = fopen(__DIR__. "/json/" . $filename, "W+");
        fwrite($create, $jsonstring);

        $json = fread($create, filesize(__DIR__. "/json/" . $filename));
        fclose($create);

        $obj = json_decode($json);

        $query_opslaan = "INSERT INTO SalesKicker (BedrijfsNaam, ContPers, TelNr, Email, Land, Plaats, POC) VALUES ('". $obj->bedrijfsNaam ."' , '". $obj->ContPers ."', '". $obj->TelNum ."', '". $obj->email ."', '". $obj->Land ."', '". $obj->Plaats ."', '". $obj->PostCode ."')";



        mysqli_query($link, $query_opslaan) or die(mysqli_error($query_opslaan));
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'ERROR: no data!';
    }

}
?>
```

It get's the data from the following C# script:

```
        if (reqCat == "bvg")
        {
            json = "{\"bedrijfsNaam\":\"" + bedrijfsNaam + "\"," +
                            "\"ContPers\":\"" + ContPers + "\"," +
                            "\"TelNum\":\"" + TelNum + "\"," +
                            "\"email\":\"" + email + "\"," +
                            "\"Land\":\"" + Land + "\"," +
                            "\"Plaats\":\"" + Plaats + "\"," +
                            "\"PostCode\":\"" + PostCode + "\"}";

            var b64bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
            b64encode = System.Convert.ToBase64String(b64bytes);

            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                byte[] sendB64 = client.UploadData("http://" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["scripturi"].ToString() + "SalesKicker.php", "POST",
                System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("b64string=" + b64encode + "&filename=" + dt.bedrijfsNaam));
            }
        }
```

This is my folder structure:

> public_html (this is where all the PHP stuff is located) -> json (the folder where it should be saved)

I don't really know what to do at the moment so I came here to post my problem. Can someone please help me out and tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What are the contents of `$jsonstring`?

Comment: does the json folder exist? the user running this code is able to create a file?

Comment: The $jsongstring contains the right data which is being decoded properly in the PHP script @jeroen

Comment: The json folder exists @TehSphinX

Comment: $filename and $jsonstring are both filled?

Comment: Yes they are both filled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That moment when a C# programmer forgets about the caches. I was a bit clumsy but after searching for the method how to clear a cache in PHP I found it. Behold, the legendary **clearstatcache()** method. My final working PHP code looks like this:

```
    if(isset($_POST['filename']) && isset($_POST['b64string']))
    {
        clearstatcache();//the solution to my problem

        $jsonstring = base64_decode($_POST['b64string']);

        $filename = $_POST['filename'] . '.json';

        $create = fopen(__DIR__. "/json/" . $filename, "w+");
        fwrite($create, $jsonstring);

        $json = fread($create, filesize(__DIR__. "/json/" . $filename));
        fclose($create);

        $obj = json_decode($json);

        $query_opslaan = "INSERT INTO SalesKicker (BedrijfsNaam, ContPers, TelNr, Email, Land, Plaats, POC) VALUES ('". $obj->bedrijfsNaam ."' , '". $obj->ContPers ."', '". $obj->TelNum ."', '". $obj->email ."', '". $obj->Land ."', '". $obj->Plaats ."', '". $obj->PostCode ."')";



        mysqli_query($link, $query_opslaan) or die(mysqli_error($query_opslaan));
    }
```

Comment: now that you mention your solution I have a question: Why are you saving the json to a file only to read it from there. Also consider two calls at the same time with different data. Shouldn't they interfere with each other when they both write to the same file? Or are the filenames NEVER the same?

Comment: I don't really know either. But my client wanted it. Don't ask me why

Answer (score 1):

Got it!
You sending 'filename' param in the POST body, but checking it in the GET array. So you don't even go into the your if(){} statement.
You need either change

```
if(isset($_GET['filename']) && isset($_POST['b64string']))
```

to

```
if(isset($_POST['filename']) && isset($_POST['b64string']))
```

either change in C#

```
            byte[] sendB64 = client.UploadData("http://" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["scripturi"].ToString() + "SalesKicker.php", "POST",
            System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("b64string=" + b64encode + "&filename=" + dt.bedrijfsNaam));
```

to

```
            byte[] sendB64 = client.UploadData("http://" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["scripturi"].ToString() + "SalesKicker.php?filename=" + dt.bedrijfsNaam, "POST",
            System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("b64string=" + b64encode));
```

Comment: Yeah right! You are even taking it from the $_POST but the if is a $_GET.

Comment: if you apply both corrections it will not work =). you need only one of them to make it work.

Comment: I changed it to GET to try it through the URL, it is supposed to be a POST

Comment: I think that it has to to something with the fopen. It still does not work. eventhough I'm working in the correct directory etc.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't sure at first but after testing here the solution:

wrong:

```
$create = fopen(__DIR__. "/json/" . $filename, "W+");
```

correct:

```
$create = fopen(__DIR__. "/json/" . $filename, "w+");
```

It's kind of stupid but capital letters in the mode are not valid. Hope this solves the issue :)

Comment: It still doesn't create the file sadly. But thanks for the answer about the capital letter!

Comment: I wonder that you did not see the error because of the capital letter. Maybe there is another php error now, that you do not see. Can you make sure you are able to see php errors?

Comment: Actually it was a warning: Warning: fopen(./test.json): failed to open stream: Inappropriate ioctl for device in ./test.php on line 3

Comment: I mostly do C# so I don't really know what causes that error. Could you explain?

Comment: The warning above was the warning we already solved (the capital letter). Did you see this warning somewhere? I wonder if there might be another warning or error that you are not seeing even now.